# C - Copy global to local array, the index get assigned instead

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

When I tried to copy a global array variable to a local array variable, for some reason, the index of these arrays got assigned instead. I have checked the address of these arrays and indexes, and make sure that their address does not overlap.

Here is my code:

```
    int ap0[3][4];
rotateboard()
{

    // rotate it counterclockwise.

    int board[3][4];

    int i,j;

    for ( i=0;i<=3;i++) //Save on a parallel array

    {

        printf("%d\n", i);

        for (j=0;j<=3;j++)

        {

            board[3-j][i] = ap0[i][j];

            printf ("%d,%d, %d = %d \n" , i, j,  board[3-j][i] ,  ap0[i][j]); 
            //this is the debug line I have inserted later

        }

    }

    for ( i=0;i<=3;i++) // reload saved data

    {

        for (j=0;j<=3;j++)

        {


            ap0[i][j] = board[i][j];

        }

    }

}
```

And this is my result:

```
0
0,0, 1 = 1
0,1, 2 = 2
0,2, 3 = 3
0,3, 4 = 4
1
1,0, 5 = 5
1,1, 6 = 6
1,2, 7 = 7
1,3, 8 = 8
2
2,9, 1 = 0
3
13,0, 0 = 0
13,1, 0 = 0
13,2, 0 = 0
13,3, 0 = 0
```

As you can see, at i=2, j=0, the value of a[2][0]( which is 9) get assigned to the variable j instead of board[2][0]. The same happen with variable i at [3][0].
I have no idea what is happening there. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Your array indexing is all over the place. Notably, if you want to iterate over an array of 3 items, you'd do `for(int i=0; i<3; i++)`. Not `<=3`. In addition, `rotateboard()` is not valid C and global variables are very bad practice...

Comment: Actually, I want to loop over 4 items, not 3. And ```rotateboard()``` is custom function, and it is still valid.

Comment: Then you might wanna allocate 4 items, not 3...

Comment: Oh, so it is like that. thank you